# Distribution plot of distances

Tags: python, distance, distribution

I have a set of only distances data in a file (have only the x-axis values) which is

```
33.682459827037576  
30.68999348321859   
8.047216910211878   
20.909036324039423  
26.05392484828342   
27.7757196126401    
19.617048707693005  
55.2330634674558    
26.548798466220653  
19.512355060320115  
9.836549191662694   
33.59471684655193   
25.430774663780888  
38.46973355769442   
29.839641418757026  
50.66538956723811   
42.41037844679059   
34.92505833924977   
29.849790619031147  
35.031699930206074  
16.73431504424367   
7.345917233402505   
30.217832483485644  
21.374023954323626  
36.55364414117968   
6.520145703893435
```

I want to plot the distribution of these distance values from this file.
How can I plot this distribution graph in Python...? I have tried the following code:-

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.interpolate
from scipy import stats
from scipy.interpolate import spline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
A=np.loadtxt('abc.txt')
z=A[0]
hist,edges = np.histogram(z, bins=100)
bin_centers = 1*(edges[:1] + edges[1:])
bin_widths = (edges[1:]-edges[:1])
plt.bar(bin_centers,hist,width=bin_widths)
plt.plot(bin_centers, hist,'r')
plt.xlabel('distance')
plt.ylabel('frequency')
plt.show()
```

I am not getting the proper distribution graph. What is the correct code to get the distribution graph?

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy import stats
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
A=np.loadtxt('abc.txt')
z=A
hist,edges = np.histogram(z, bins=100)
bin_centers = (edges[:1] + edges[1:])/2
bin_widths = (edges[1:]-edges[:1])
plt.bar(bin_centers,hist,width=1)
plt.plot(bin_centers, hist,'r')
plt.xlabel('distance')
plt.ylabel('frequency')
plt.show()

df=pd.DataFrame({"xs":bin_centers,"ys":hist})
df.to_csv("FileName.csv")
```

Comment: I tried using your code, but i am getting just a single histogram bar around distances 33.6 to 33.8. But there are no distribution plotted for other values....

Comment: I'm sorry. I didn't read carefully enough. A is going to just be an array of values presumably (not a list of lists). That is to say, you don't need to do z=A[0]. You should do z=A or just use A. Also, you probably don't want 100 bins.

Comment: If i want just like a curve/line plot (with points connected) how can i get it...?          
Second, How can i save these values into a file (the x and y values that is been shown in the plot)...?

Comment: I've edited my answer above to give what i think you want. Let me know if it fulfills your aims. You really want both the line plot and the histogram?

Comment: Yes, Thank you very much for the answers. Your previous code as well as the above-edited code works well.